# iOS web view with urlstartswith

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiwebview

if there is someone who can help me to create a simple iOS app , i need just the code

The app needs a WebView wich will load the following url http://www.applicationurl.com/?param=(udid)
The param udid needs to be static so it will never change

The app will have 1 Back button for the webview and 3 simple ifUrlStartsWith if's

***if the link in webview is `<a href="tel://phonenumer">Click to Call</a>` it will call that phonenumber***

**if the link in webview is `<a href="loc://show-location">Apple Map's</a>` it will open the Apple maps to a static adress , the adress could be stored in NSSTRING *mapadress=@"Romania Street Haleluia nr.2";***

***if the link in webview is `<a href="exit://exit-app">Exit App</a>` it will automatically close the app***

Can any one help me please ? i always get stuck at urlstartswith and the current url is not showing up.

The code i'm using

```
    //
//  ViewController.m
//  Aqua Park President
//
//  Created by Alex Bonta on 7/13/14.
//  Copyright (c) 2014 Aqua President. All rights reserved.
//

#import "ViewController.h"


@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController
@synthesize webView;

- (void)viewDidLoad
{



    // GET THE PHONE UDID
    NSString *udid=[[[UIDevice currentDevice] identifierForVendor] UUIDString];
    udid=[udid substringToIndex:5];






    // Loading the url adress with the param of the uinique id
    NSString *string = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://app.aquapark-felix.ro/?email=%@",udid];
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:string];
    [webView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url]];
    NSString *currentURL = webView.request.URL.absoluteString;

    - (BOOL) webView;(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType {
        //Catching URLs and telling the app what to do
        if ([[[request URL] scheme] isEqualToString:@"tel"]) {
            NSLog((@"ASA"));
        }


    }
    [super viewDidLoad];




}









- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}






@end
```

Comment: Show the code you're using. Note that your `exit` option will usually get you rejected during app store review and you should not close the app like that.

Comment: Show us what you have tried until now

Comment: I've updated my answer. I would watch as I don't think apple like people getting UDID of devices anymore.. The definitely don't like quitting apps the way you want to.

Comment: Whatever you don't have "`if the link in webview is <a href="exit://exit-app">Exit App</a> it will automatically close the app`" Apple will reject apps that close themselves like this. If the user wants to leave your app they will use the home button to exist.

Comment: Also `[super viewDidLoad];` should always come first not last.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have cleaned up your code as well as answering it. Please see the comments in the code for an explanation of the code and also please see the [Apple URL Schemes Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/iPhoneURLScheme_Reference/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007899-CH1-SW1). The Below code has been tested and works when you pass in a correct URL scheme such as

**HTML** for making phone call

`<a href="tel:1-408-555-5555">1-408-555-5555</a>`

**Natiave** for making phone call

`tel:1-408-555-5555`

**HTML** for accessing maps app

`<a href="http://maps.apple.com/?daddr=San+Francisco,+CA&saddr=cupertino">Directions</a>`

**Native** for accessing maps app

`http://maps.apple.com/?daddr=San+Francisco,+CA&saddr=cupertino`

If you haven't configured these properly it will not work. As you are coming from a website you will need the HTML versions.

```
//
//  ViewController.m
//  Aqua Park President
//
//  Created by Alex Bonta on 7/13/14.
//  Copyright (c) 2014 Aqua President. All rights reserved.
//

#import "ViewController.h"


@implementation ViewController
// This can be removed as it is done automcatically for you.
//@synthesize webView;

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
   // A call to the super must come first.
   [super viewDidLoad];

    // Construct a url request with the UUID string and pass it to the _webView
    [_webView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://app.aquapark-felix.ro/?email=%@",[[[[UIDevice currentDevice] identifierForVendor] UUIDString] substringToIndex:5]]]]];
}


- (BOOL) webView;(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType
{   
    // Check whether the URL scheme is of "tel"
    // "loc" will not open the apple maps app this code is done so it will.
    if([request.URL.scheme isEqualToString:@"tel"] || [request.URL.absoluteString hasPrefix:@"http://maps.apple.com/?q"]) {
        // We need to make sure we can actually open the urls that have been passed in.
        // We do this for two reason 1) if we couldn't it would be a bad user experience 
        // and 2) you can't make calls on a iPod.
        if([[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL:request.URL]) {
            // Yes we can make a phone call so lets make it.
            // Based on your number being formatted correctly if it's not then it will not work.
            [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:request.URL];
        }
        // If all else fails and we can't open the url just return no.
        // I would recommend a UIAlertView here to tell the user.
        return NO;
    }
    // As for exiting the app don't do this at all.

    // Every other URL just return YES and continue with the Request.
    return YES;
}

@end
```

Comment: Popeye i got this error at if([[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL:request.url]) {

Property url not found on object of type NSURLRequest

EDIT: resolved it with CAPSLOCK :))

Comment: @Downvoter please leave reason for downvote. This is tested code and does what the user wanted.

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to get the URL Scheme (http, loc, tel etc)

```
- (BOOL) webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType {
    //Catching URLs and telling the app what to do
    if ([[[request URL] scheme] isEqualToString:@"tel"]) {
         // Code

        return NO;
    }
    return YES;
}
```

And so on for your other schemes.

This needs to go outside of viewDidload. See below.

```
//  ViewController.m
//  Aqua Park President
//
//  Created by Alex Bonta on 7/13/14.
//  Copyright (c) 2014 Aqua President. All rights reserved.
//

#import "ViewController.h"


@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController
@synthesize webView;

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    // GET THE PHONE UDID
    NSString *udid=[[[UIDevice currentDevice] identifierForVendor] UUIDString];
    udid=[udid substringToIndex:5];

    // Loading the url adress with the param of the uinique id
    NSString *string = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://app.aquapark-felix.ro/?email=%@",udid];
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:string];
    [webView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url]];
    NSString *currentURL = webView.request.URL.absoluteString;

    [super viewDidLoad];
}

- (BOOL) webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType {
    //Catching URLs and telling the app what to do
    if ([[[request URL] scheme] isEqualToString:@"tel"]) {
        NSLog((@"ASA"));
        return NO;
    }
    return YES;
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@end
```

Comment: I don't know where to implement that

Comment: I have explained what to do.

Comment: I am getting Use of undeclared identifier 'REQUEST'

Comment: Can you update your question with the current code you're trying?

Comment: Now i get 3 errors 

first for the BOOL expected method body and 
Conflicting return type in implementation of 'webview': UIWebView vs 'BOO;' (aka 'signe char')

and the second
Use of undeclared identifier 'REQUEST'

Comment: You changed a colon `- (BOOL) webView:` to a semicolon `- (BOOL) webView;`. Make sure it is a colon.

Comment: Done it thanks but now i get a 
Control reaches end of non-void function§

Comment: But now if i press a WebView link which starts with <a href="tel:number">Call me</a> the NSLOG doesn't output something

Comment: As per my comment on the question `[super viewDidLoad]` should always come first not last. When you call a methods super it should always be the first line. What's with the double `()` in `NSLog((@"ASA"));`?